# Can you detect when iCloud is updating?

Tags: ios, core-data, notifications

I realise I use the `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` notification to merge changes once they have arrived from iCloud. However, my understanding is that this notification is triggered once the have already arrived. Is there any way to detect that changes are arriving? In other words, is there any way that I can tell when Core Data is downloading updates from iCloud so I can show an indication of this to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Apple doesn't let you know much about the state of their iCloud process. The best  you can do, I believe, is to listen for the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification`, you can then parse out `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType` key in the `userInfo`. Then you can manage the user interface while the database updates.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll look into that. This wouldn't necessary if iCloud syncing wasn't so flaky sometimes! :-/